# Tensorflow error: function_optimizer failed and layout failed while training subclassed keras.Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Creating a Seq2Seq keras model for summary generation by subclassing keras.Model. The model works fine on smaller toy samples but I get tensorflow errors when I start training on real dataset.
Code and Model arch are as follows:

```
class Summary_Generator(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vs_text = 4280,
               
    def call(self, inputs):
       en_outputs = self.encoder(source_seq,initial_states)
       en_states = en_outputs[1:]
       de_states = en_states
       print("enc call over, dec call begins")
       dec_outputs = self.decoder(dec_in, de_states, en_outputs[0])
       print("dec execution over ...") 
       return dec_outputs

class Encoder_LSTM(keras.Model):
     def __init__():
     def call():

class Decoder_LSTM_Attn(keras.Model):
     def __init__():
     def call():
         print("lstm_out shape: ",lstm_out.shape)
         logits = self.ws(lstm_out)
         print("logits shape: ",logits.shape)

def train_one_step(text, summary, in_states):
    summary_input = summary[:, :-1]
    summary_gt = summary[:, 1:]
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = None
        for i in range((summary.shape[1])-1): 
            dec_in = tf.expand_dims(summary[:, i], 1)
            print(i,  end=", ")
         
            de_outputs = sg([text, dec_in, in_states[0], in_states[1]])
        
            print("back", end = " ")
```

The code words as expected with toy samples, but fails to run even for one complete batch with training on real data. Tried de-bugging with print statements to find out where the flow stops. train_step() begins execution and i get i=0 printed on the screen, it then executes object of Summary_Generator class, encoder executes, i get "enc ends decoder begins" printed and then I get shape of logits also printed.
Here is where my confusion starts, instead of getting "back" printed as expected from the code, there is second round of execution, then too it executes fine till the end, as shape of logits is printed on the screen. Which return statement is not working and why?
Why is the code block executed twice?
This is a snapshot of the errors:

```
0,
enc call over, dec call begins
lstm out shape :  (None, 1000)
logits shape:  (None, 6764)
dec execution over ...
enc call over, dec call begins
lstm out shape :  (None, 1000)
logits shape:  (None, 6764)
dec execution over ...
```

Error:

```
2021-06-02 05:28:27.130200: E 
tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:563] function_optimizer 
failed: Invalid argument: Input 0 of node 
encoder_lstm_lstm_statefulpartitionedcall_10_RetVal was passed float from 
encoder_lstm/lstm/StatefulPartitionedCall:13 incompatible with expected 
variant.
2021-06-02 05:28:27.154121: E 
tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:563] layout failed: Out 
of range: src_output = 30, but num_outputs is only 30
2021-06-02 05:28:27.187119: E 
tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:563] function_optimizer 
failed: Invalid argument: Input 0 of node 
encoder_lstm_lstm_statefulpartitionedcall_10_RetVal was passed float from 
encoder_lstm/lstm/StatefulPartitionedCall:13 incompatible with expected 
variant.
<br>stack of other messages that ends with <br>
File "/home/narora/anaconda3/envs/tf_env/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 6653, in 
raise_from_not_ok_status
six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when 
allocating tensor with shape[500,2000] and type float on 
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc 
[Op:ZerosLike]
```

When all neural computations have been succesfully completed, why will there be an OOM error and if it has not returned back (as I did not get "back" printed even once, which function optimizer failed?

Comment: I am running this program on remote linux server with GPU machine and at the time of execution, only this code sample was running.  Also, the shape in the OOV error message is same as I set the number of lstm units. For the current code execution, no of lstm units was 500